# Parallel ajax calls limitations/pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, parallel-processing

I have a question about parallel ajax call.

In my project I load a list of elements (variable between 10 - 200). These elements have detailed information in the persitancy. I would like to load these details via ajax, because including them with the initial element load will take to much time and leave the user waiting.

**Question**:

Is it an acceptable pattern to start multiple parallel ajax call after showing the initial loaded element list or is it a no-go to start a unkown number (in my case max of 200) of parallel ajax calls?

1. If it is ok: are there any browser limitation I have to deal with?
2. If it is not ok: Would chaining be the right pattern?

**Attempts**:

I try to inspect how websites like facebook do the data loading but I don't really see what they are doing.

Comment: It mainly depend on your server.
But what about pagination, loading ten by ten ?

Comment: Paging is allready implemented @SteevePitis, the complete collection is about ~800 elements and the user can do paging with 10, 50, 100 or 200 elements per page.